# Solr RegexTransformer only delviers first match to multivalued field

Tags: regex, solr, multivalue

I want to find hashtags in a comment coming from DB. For that I use the RegexTransformer of Solr together with a multivalued field. My problem is, that the Transformer only delivers the first match of the String and not all matches.

boards.xml: `<field column="hashtag" sourceColName="comment" regex="(#[^.!\s]+)" />`
schema.xml: `<field name="hashtag" type="string" multiValued="true" />`

so e.g. **"This is a #good #comment"** as input should save **#good** and **#comment** in the multivalued field, but only #good arrives.

I know I am not the best when it comes to Regex, but according to http://www.regexplanet.com it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out, that this behaviour is by purpose. It always only returns one match. I solved the problem by using the [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer)

```
function CommentPieces(row){
        var reg = new RegExp(/(#[^.!\s]+)/g);
        var arr = new java.util.ArrayList();
        while((result = reg.exec(row.get('comment'))) !== null) {
            if(!arr.contains(result[0])){
                arr.add(result[0]);
            }
        }
        row.put('hashtag', arr);
        return row;
    }
```